# Checkbox in a ColdFusion form

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, cfml

My code is below. I need to have both of the checkboxes checked by default when the page loads. This displays a result of the query. Now when one of the checkboxes is unchecked the form needs to be submitted and different query results need to be displayed. The checkboxes are always being checked even when I uncheck one. Can someone please guide me here?

```
<form action="abc.cfm?show=yes" method="post" name="myform">
    <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="chkbox" id="chkbox1"> <strong> Agreement Only</strong> 
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="chk" id="chk1">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="chkbox" id="chkbox2"> <strong>Active Employees</strong> 
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="chk" id="chk2">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="Submit" name="submitnow" value="View now">
        </td>
    </table>
</form>

<cfif isdefined("form.chk1")>
    query 1
<cfelseif isdefined("form.chk2")>
    query 2
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you've named the checkboxes the same thing and are always checking them, so why would they not be checked?

You need to name them uniquely and check if the key exists in the form once the page has been submitted. Or display the box as checked when the form has not been submitted

The form has not been submitted - `NOT structKeyExists(form,'fieldnames')`

The form has been submitted and chkbox1 was selected - `structKeyExists(form,'chkbox1')`

```
 <td>
   <input type="checkbox"<cfif NOT structKeyExists(form,'fieldnames') OR structKeyExists(form,'chkbox1')> checked="checked"</cfif> name="chkbox1" id="chkbox1"> <strong> Agreement                        Only</strong> 
    &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="chk" id="chk1">
     <input type="checkbox"<cfif NOT structKeyExists(form,'fieldnames') OR structKeyExists(form,'chkbox2')> checked="checked"</cfif> name="chkbox2" id="chkbox2"> <strong>Active                  Employees</strong> 
   &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="chk" id="chk2">
  </td>
```

Comment: Sorry that was a type the checkboxes are chk1 and chk2

Comment: @user747291: Please fix this in your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you could accomplish what your trying to do.  I wasn't sure what the purpose of your hidden fields were, so I modified a few things to try to make life a little easier.

Some people may suggest structkeyexists, but I didnt want to introduce a new command that you may not be familiar with.

```
<cfparam name="form.chkbox" default="">

<form action="abc.cfm?show=yes" method="post" name="myform">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" <cfif form.chkbox eq "" or listfind(form.chkbox, 1)>checked="checked"</cfif> name="chkbox" id="chkbox1" value="1">
        <strong> Agreement                        Only</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" <cfif form.chkbox eq "" or listfind(form.chkbox, 2)>checked="checked"</cfif> name="chkbox" id="chkbox1" value="2">
        <strong>Active                  Employees</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;
</td>
      <td><input type="Submit" name="submitnow" value="View now"></td>
  </table>
</form>
<cfif listfind(form.chkbox, 1) and listfind(form.chkbox,2)>
  query 1
  query 2
</cfif>
```

Comment: thanks Steve, I need to display a qeury result when both the checkboxes are checked. Can I use this condition for that? <cfif Listfind(form.chkbox, 1) and listfind(form.chkbox, 2)> Query 3 </cfif>

Comment: The 2 checkboxes are still remaining checked, even after i uncheck one and hit View now. Any ideas?

Comment: I just tested everything on my box.  Copy and paste all the highlighted code above and start with a clean form.  By default, both boxes are checked.  If I click view now, they remain checked and the query 1 query 2 displays.  If I deselect agreement only, and hit view now, it reloads with active employees highlighted.  I can uncheck active employees and check agreement only and click view now and agreement only stays hightlighted.

Comment: For checking the checkbox is not checked, is this right? <cfif not listfind(form.chkbox, 2)>? I am still not able to get the results rights.

Comment: <cfif listfind(form.checkbox,2) eq 0> is my prefered way of doing it... it may work the other way.

Comment: *I am still not able to get the results rights* Then something in your code is different than what steve posted, because it works as advertised. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15770423/edit) to include the **exact** code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the inputs (`chk1` and `chk2`) DO exist in the form scope when the form is submitted. Their values, however, are empty.

To demonstrate this, dump out the `form` scope before your `isdefined` checks.

```
<cfdump var="#form#" label="form scope">
```

[image: form scope dump]

You need to be checking for the `value` or `length` attributes of the inputs.

```
<cfif len(form.chk1)>
    query 1
</cfif>
```

**BUT!**

This doesn't actually seem to be what you want to do. `chk1` and `chk2` are your *TEXT* inputs, not your *CHECKBOX* inputs.

If you want to be acting based on the *checkboxes*, you need to be checking the `value` of the checkbox inputs - which brings us to another issue: you didn't set a `value` attribute for the checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1"...>
```

Now, you need to `param` the values of these checkboxes to ensure that fields exist at all

```
<cfparam name="form.chkbox1" value="0">
```

And then check the value

```
<cfif form.chkbox1 EQ 1>
    query 1
</cfif>
```

Comment: your initial statement and dump does not line up with the original post's code. chk1 and chk2 are not the names of the hidden fields.

Comment: I copy and pasted the code from his post to do the dump - with the change that he mentioned being a typo in another comment.

Comment: I have this working now except for one thing, when I uncheck both the check boxes, and hit view now, because the cfparam is being set the boxes are always being checked. Will any javascript function help me reset the value of the form.chkbox?

Comment: Why are you defaulting the values to? If you default them to 0 and only pre-check them if the values are 1, then they wouldn't be pre-checked when the form is loaded.