# checkbox on page load in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have 2 check boxes like below on a coldfusion form. On page load I want both to be checked 
and display  a query result depending on which checkbox is checked. I have the below code working fine except for the scernario where I uncheck both the checkboxes and hit view now. As im setting

```
form.chkbox=""
```

on page load they are remaining checked even after I uncheck them. How can i make them remain unchecked upon page load. I tried using the JS function, but it doesnt seem to work

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  function callme(){
var box1 = document.getElementById('chkbox1').checked;
var box2 = document.getElementById('chkbox2').checked;
if (box1 && box2){
          alert("checked") ;
}else{    
box1.checked = false;
box2.checked = false;
}
}

 </script>  

    <cfset form.chkbox=""> 

    <form action="view_emp_qual.cfm?show=yes" method="post" name="Myform">
     <table align="center">
     <tr>
    <td>
  <cfif isDefined("form.chkbox") and (form.chkbox eq "" or listfind(form.chkbox, 1))>
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="chkbox" id="chkbox1" value="1">      
  <cfelse>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"  id="chkbox1" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="chkbox"  id="chkbox1" value="1">
  </cfif>
    <strong> Agreement Only</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <cfif isDefineD("form.chkbox") and (form.chkbox eq "" or listfind(form.chkbox, 2))>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="chkbox" id="chkbox2" value="2">
    <cfelse>
     <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"  id="chkbox2" value="2">
      <input type="hidden" name="chkbox"  id="chkbox2" value="2">
    </cfif>

    <strong>Active Employees</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;
   </td>
  <td><input type="Submit" name="submitnow" value="View Selected" class="button"  onclick="return callme();">      </td>

      </tr>
      </table>
      </form> 


    <cfif not isDefined("form.chkbox")>
     Query1
     <cfelseif isDefined("form.chkbox") and ( listfind(form.chkbox, 1) eq 0 and listfind(form.chkbox, 2) eq 1)>
      Query 2
     <cfelseif isDefineD("form.chkbox") and (listfind(form.chkbox, 1) eq 1 and listfind(form.chkbox, 2) eq 0)>
    query 3
     <cfelse>
    query4
    </cfif>
```

Comment: wasn't this resolved here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770423/checkbox-in-a-coldfusion-form

Comment: `On page load I want both to be checked` and you also say `How can i make them remain unchecked upon page load.` Which is it?

Comment: First time when the page loads , they have to be checked. Which is working. When i uncheck both of them and hit view now, they are still being checked because of this <cfset form.chkbox="">. I hope its clear now thanks

Comment: @user747291 then change the logic to not include `form.chkbox eq ""` to not check them?

Comment: im kind of totally stuck at this can you give me an example having a messy time with this thanks

Comment: @user747291 the other question you posted has answers that do exactly what you're asking for help with

Comment: are you submitting the form in same page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting the form in same page then following code may solve your purpose.

I have made some adjustment with your main code. Please have a look.

```
    <cfdump var="#form#" label="before">
    <!---flag for checking if form has submitted or not--->
    <cfif Not isDefined("form.submitnow")>
        <cfset form.chkbox = "1,2">
    </cfif>
    <cfdump var="#form#" label="after">
    <cfif isDefined("form.chkbox") > 
    <cfdump var="#listfind(form.chkbox, 1)#" ><br>
    <cfdump var="#listfind(form.chkbox, 2)#" >
    </cfif>


        <form action="" method="post" name="Myform">
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!---I have removed hidden fields and made a few changes in conditional checking    --->
                        <cfif isDefined("form.chkbox") and (listfind(form.chkbox, 1))> 
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="chkbox" id="chkbox1" value="1"><span>1</span>      
                        <cfelse>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"  id="chkbox1" value="1"><span>2</span> 
                        </cfif>

                        <strong> Agreement Only</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <cfif isDefineD("form.chkbox") and (listfind(form.chkbox, 2))>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="chkbox" id="chkbox2" value="2"><span>3</span> 
                        <cfelse>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox"  id="chkbox2" value="2"><span>4</span> 
                        </cfif>
                        <strong>Active Employees</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="Submit" name="submitnow" value="View Selected" class="button">      
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
          </form> 


        <cfif not isDefined("form.chkbox")>
         Query1
         <cfelseif isDefined("form.chkbox") and ( listfind(form.chkbox, 1) eq 0 and listfind(form.chkbox, 2) eq 1)>
          Query 2
         <cfelseif isDefineD("form.chkbox") and (listfind(form.chkbox, 1) eq 1 and listfind(form.chkbox, 2) eq 0)>
        query 3
     <cfelse>
    query4
    </cfif>
```