# Checkboxes not checked upon submit in coldfusion form

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am posting this question here again as I need further help from my previous question [Checkbox in a ColdFusion form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15770423/checkbox-in-a-coldfusion-form)

```
<form action="view_emp_qual.cfm?show=yes" id="Myform" method="post" name="myform">

    <table id="tab1" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" onclick="return callme();" 
            <cfif structKeyExists(form, 'chkbox3')>
                checked="checked"
            </cfif>
            name="chkbox3" id="chkbox3"> 
            <strong>All Employees</strong>

            <input type="checkbox" onclick="return callme1();" 
            <cfif NOT structKeyExists(form, 'fieldnames') OR structKeyExists(form, 'chkbox1') OR (structKeyExists(form, 'fieldnames') and structKeyExists(form, 'chkbox1'))>
                checked="checked"
            </cfif>
            name="chkbox1" id="chkbox1" /> 
            <strong>Agreement Only</strong>

            <input type="checkbox" onclick="return callme1();" 
            <cfif NOT structKeyExists(form, 'fieldnames') OR structKeyExists(form, 'chkbox2') OR (structKeyExists(form, 'fieldnames') and structKeyExists(form, 'chkbox2'))>
                checked="checked"
            </cfif>
            name="chkbox2" id="chkbox2"/> 
            <strong>Active Employees</strong>

            <td>
            <input type="Submit" name="submitnow" value="View Selected" class="button1">
            <td>
            <input type="button" name="Back" value="Back to Previous Menu" onclick="javascript:document.location.href('qualyrs_maint.cfm');" class="button1">
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I have 3 checkboxes now, out of which the last two needs to be checked on page load and show query results. And the first one has to be checked when the last two are unchecked and show the query results accordingly.

Now I have a sorting column feature on the page. Like this

```
<cfif isdefined("form.order_by") and form.order_by eq "EMPLID">
    background-color:##
    <cfif sort_order eq "asc">
        666666
    <cfelse>
        000000
    </cfif>
</cfif>
;"
onClick="sortBy('EMPLID');Sorting.style.display='block';">
EMPLID
<cfif isdefined("form.sort_order") and isdefined("form.order_by") and ucase(form.sort_order) eq 'ASC' and ucase(form.order_by) eq 'EMPLID'>
    <img src="images/desc.jpg">
<cfelseif isdefined("form.sort_order") and isdefined("form.order_by") and ucase(form.sort_order) eq 'DESC' and ucase(form.order_by) eq 'EMPLID'>
    <img src="images/asc.jpg">
</cfif>
```

This the JS for that

```
<script language="Javascript">
    function sortBy(order) {
            foo = document.getElementById("order_by_id");
            bar = document.getElementById("sort_order_id"); 
            <!---if (foo.value == order) {
                //same thing again, so flip the sort
                if (bar.value == 'DESC'){
                    bar.value = 'ASC';
                    }
                else{
                    bar.value = 'DESC';}
                //bar.value = bar.value == "ASC" ? "DESC" : "ASC";  
            } else {
                //new sort order, so make it ASC
                bar.value = "ASC";
            }--->
            foo.value = order;
            sort.submit();
        }
</script>

<cfscript>
    if(IsDefined('form.sort_order'))
    {
        if(form.sort_order IS 'ASC')
            sort_order_value = 'DESC';
        else
            sort_order_value = 'ASC';
    }
    else
        sort_order_value = 'ASC';
</cfscript>

<form action="view_emp_qual.cfm?show=yes" method="post" name="sort">
    <cfoutput>
        <cfparam name="order_by" default="">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_by" id="order_by_id" value="#order_by#">
        <input type="hidden" name="sort_order" id="sort_order_id" value="#sort_order_value#">

        <cfif Isdefined("Form.fieldnames")>
            <cfloop index="fieldname" list=#form.fieldnames#>
                <cfset fieldvalue = Evaluate("form." & #fieldname#)>
                <cfif not ("order_by,sort_order") contains fieldname>
                    <input type="hidden" name=##fieldname## value="#fieldvalue#">
                </cfif>
            </cfloop>
        </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
</form>
```

Now I have everything working as I need, except that, on the page load when the last two checkboxes are checked, and I hit the sort column icon, then the first checkbox is getting checked. Please advice as to where my code is going wrong. thanks

Comment: hi all any comments please? on this one

Comment: Are you still using `cfparam` tags to initialize your form fields (per your previous question)?

Comment: no im not using cfparam

Comment: I don't think you have shared all of the relevant code here but the other thing I notice is that you are only checking for the existence of the 'chkbox3' form field, not it's value. So if it exists in the submission that box will get checked.

Comment: I have updated the code, when I check the form fields in the debugging mode I do not see any value to checkbox3. All I see is the form fieldnames defined upon sorting.

Comment: That's what I am saying - you are only checking for the existence of the 'chkbox3' form field.  If it exists the checkbox will be checked. That is generally how checkboxes work however. They are only submitted if they are selected. So if you are seeing the form field defined, it is being submitted somewhere in your code. I don't really understand what you are attempting to do with your newly posted code. Setting "hidden" form fields to form fields that already exist? I thought you were attempting to re-populate the existing form?

Answer (score 0):

Your question/approach is quite messy and I have spent a lot of minutes trying to understand what you are doing. I noticed errors but couldn't fix your code because it was difficult to read some of the things you did so, I have created something similar below - in a rush. It uses the same form for sorting and presentation and allows you to use several other 'order' keys (empid ...). I have also commented it so you can understand what I'm doing at every point. Clicking on the order link re-submits the form, passes the same values currently in the form and when processing the form submission, you can use the sort_order_value and the order_by_value for whatever you want to.

```
<!--- initialized needed variables --->
<cfscript>
    isPost = structKeyExists(form, 'fieldnames'); //if form was submitted
    chkbox1Selected = structKeyExists(form, 'chkbox1'); //if chkbox1 is selected
    chkbox2Selected = structKeyExists(form, 'chkbox2'); //if chkbox2 is selected
    chkbox3Selected = structKeyExists(form, 'chkbox3'); //if chkbox3 is selected
    param name="order_by_value" default="EMPLID"; //default order_by_value is EMPLID
    if(structKeyExists(form, 'sort_order') AND form.sort_order IS 'ASC') //if  sort order was specified and it was ASC, change to DESC
        sort_order_value = 'DESC';
    else //if order wasnt selected, default is ASC and if DESC was sent, change to ASC
        sort_order_value = 'ASC';
</cfscript>
<cfoutput>
    <!--- for debugging --->
    isPost: #isPost#<br>
    chkbox1Selected: #chkbox1Selected#<br>
    chkbox2Selected: #chkbox2Selected#<br>
    chkbox3Selected: #chkbox3Selected#<br>
    sort_order_value: #sort_order_value#<br>
    <cfif structKeyExists(form, 'sort_order')>
        form.sort_order: #form.sort_order#<br>
    </cfif>
    <!--- end of debugging --->


    <form action="view_emp_qual.cfm?show=yes" id="Myform" method="post" name="myform">
        <!--- brought this here to save the current order value and the sort order being use. Meaning it can be used with other order keys --->
        <input type="hidden" name="order_by" id="order_by_id" value="#order_by_value#">
        <input type="hidden" name="sort_order" id="sort_order_id" value="#sort_order_value#">
        <table id="tab1" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="return callme();"  <cfif chkbox3Selected> checked="checked" </cfif> name="chkbox3" id="chkbox3">
                <strong>All Employees</strong>

                <input type="checkbox" onclick="return callme1();" <cfif (NOT isPost) OR chkbox1Selected> checked="checked" </cfif> name="chkbox1" id="chkbox1" />
                <strong>Agreement Only</strong>

                <input type="checkbox" onclick="return callme1();" <cfif (NOT isPost) OR chkbox2Selected> checked="checked" </cfif> name="chkbox2" id="chkbox2"/>
                <strong>Active Employees</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="Submit" name="submitnow" value="View Selected" class="button1">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <!-- my code here can be optimized. I am only trying to represent the status of the order key. Whether it is being used (and is asc or desc) or it is not being used-->
                    <cfif order_by_value eq "EMPLID">
                        <cfif sort_order_value eq "asc"> <!--- comparison is case insenstive --->
                            <a href="##" style="background-color:##666666;font-weight:bold" onClick="sortBy('EMPLID');"> EMPLID desc<img src="images/desc.jpg"> </a> <!--- bolden order_by if currently used --->
                        <cfelse>
                            <a href="##" style="background-color:##000000;font-weight:bold" onClick="sortBy('EMPLID');"> EMPLID asc<img src="images/asc.jpg"> </a>
                        </cfif>
                    <cfelse>
                        <a href="##" style="" onClick="sortBy('EMPLID');"> EMPLID </a> <!--- inherits current sort_order_value when clicked --->
                    </cfif>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" name="Back" value="Back to Previous Menu" onclick="javascript:document.location.href('qualyrs_maint.cfm');" class="button1">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>


</cfoutput>
<script language="Javascript">
    function sortBy(order) {
        foo = document.getElementById("order_by_id");
        foo.value = order;
        myform.submit();
    }
</script>
```